# Interactive CLI packages - checkboxes & selection

Tags: python, ruby, go, scripting, command-line-interface

I am trying to learn more about making some cool CLI interfaces to provide the options for some local scripts. By digging into the source of the [yeoman-generator](http://yeoman.github.io/generator/adapter.js.html) I was able to come across [inquirer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/inquirer) for Node, which is how I learned that it was possible. (Example of what it looks like below)

Specifically I want to be able to do something like display a list of checkboxes and use some key to select multiple options and then continue.

Is anyone familiar with any packages/modules for other CLI languages that would allow me to do something similar? I like Node, but do not generally use it for scripting. Something in Python, Ruby or Go (I just started playing with Go) would be ideal

[image: inquirer-checkbox]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*The* package which has been around for many years is called Curses. The modern version package is actually called nCurses, but is still compatible with the original one. Here's a sample screenshot:

[image]

I haven't tried it with Unicode characters - it should work, and then you can use more fancy characters to mark checkbuttons and such.

Curses is available for Python, Ruby and Go (and C and many other languages!).

Comment: nCurses is actually the lowest level for making this kind of application. People made things like [termbox](https://github.com/nsf/termbox-go) and such.

Comment: @depado: Actually, the lowest level of implementation is implementing something like Curses yourself, with the actual Esc-code, creation/deletion of the windows. I did that too, time ago :-)

Comment: Nice, I did not know it was actually possible to achieve something like that without spending years on it haha. Good to know though :)

Comment: Well, one learns a lot from doing it. Particularly respect for what they did in nCurses.

Answer (score 1):

I am a bit late to the party, but for anyone looking for such libraries now:

- Go - [charmbracelet/bubbletea](https://github.com/charmbracelet/bubbletea)
- Python - [petereon/beaupy](https://github.com/petereon/beaupy)
- Shell - [charmbracelet/gum](https://github.com/charmbracelet/gum)

Disclaimer: I am a maintainer of beaupy